# parsing files outside root confusion

Tags: php, parsing, ini

say i have c:\usr\local\public as my root directory. this is public and what is accessed through the url.

if i want to use ini files or anything that i dont want on the public directory and want it say in c:\usr\local\nonpublic i would use the /../nonpublic/file.ini to access it?
example:

```
parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../nonpublic/config.ini');
```

i know this may be stupid as hell but im confused on how i would parse it correctly being as im still new to this.

is there also a way to make a directory in php.ini/apache.conf where it can be located and parsed this way? that way when i parse it in php i can just use the filename instead of its relative/absolute location?
example:

```
parse_ini_file('config.ini');
```

i tried googling some examples but maybe my wording for the search didnt give too many results which left me even more confused.

Comment: No you can not access it through url. What you can do is to read by `file_get_contents` and `echo` it.

Comment: added examples to maybe help better with what i am looking for..

Comment: forget my previous comment, I did not read carefully your questuin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set include path.

```
<?php
$path = 'c:\usr\local\nonpublic';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
$iniArray = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
```

You can set this `include_path` in your php.ini too, so you do not need to do the `set_include_path` every time.

Comment: thanks. worked great. i set the include path in php.ini and added my config there and just used $CONF = parse_ini_file('cfg.ini'); then $VALUE1 = $CONF['key01'];
$VALUE2 = $CONF['key02']; and it took added my value where i wanted it without it being in source. much appreciated!